# euro sign not displayed in text field when using jquery tabs plugin

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I see different behaviour when using html input tag vs spring form tab library with Jquery tabs plug in

This works : showing currectly '€' in the text field

```
<input type="text" value="${requestattr.name}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

This does not work : shows ascii code `&#128;` in the text field

```
<form:input maxlength="40" path="name" readonly="true"/>
```

Can anyone help what is causing this wierd behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the spring character encoding filter. In order to do this, add this into the web.xml file

```
<!-- Encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps.